# Is DS PhotoEditor SDK deprecated?

Tags: android

It uses onActivityResult and startActivityForResult  methods which are deprecated in android.

```
startActivityForResult(dsPhotoEditorIntent, 200);



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         switch (requestCode) {

             case 200:

                 Uri outputUri = data.getData();

                 // handle the result uri as you want, such as display it in an imageView;

                 // imageView.setImageURI(outputUri);     

                 break;

         }

     }

 }
```

SDK Changelog says :

Android SDK:
Version 2.3 (v10):  //Latest
i) Support Android Q
ii) Migrate to AndroidX

So can we use it with registerForActivityResult method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can make it much simpler,**

```
private var intentLaunch=
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult() 
{result ->
    
}
```

Then you can just launch your intent here,

```
intentLaunch.launch(dsPhotoEditorIntent)
```

You won't need a request code for this. You can directly handle it from the result. Here is the kotlin code sample. You can write similarly in java

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    doSomeOperations();
                }
            }
        });

public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(dsPhotoEditorIntent);
}
```